# "Go in the front door", "go through/by the front door", or "go inside through/by the front door"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell which of the following sentences sound the most natural.

> Let **go in** the front door. The back one is locked.
>
> Let **go in through** the front door. The back one is locked.
>
> Let **go in by** the front door. The back one is locked.
>
> Let **go inside through** the front door. The back one is locked
>
> Let **go inside by** the front door. The back one is locked.

What I'm trying to say is let's get inside the house by way of the front door. Are all natural and correct? If none of the sentences sounds particularly idiomatic, how would you say that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is the most natural in everyday speech:

> Let's **go in** the front door. The back one is locked.

These are also correct:

> Let's **go in through** the front door. The back one is locked.

> Let's **go in by** the front door. The back one is locked.

These are much less usual and slightly awkward (even though "Let's go inside" on its own is fine):

> Let's **go inside** through the front door. The back one is locked

> Let's **go inside** by the front door. The back one is locked.

Comment: I have hardly ever heard the first one, the one which you said is the most natural. I have heard and read the second and the third one, more often than all others.